# change php session jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I'm trying to create PHP sessions on my website for users who have accounts and are logged in, so they don't have to log in every time. I did a bit of research and I have this so far:

top of index.php

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
```

beginning of body- here I check whether they're logged in or not, and their user name/user id (so I can do db calls)

```
<?php
    $loggedIn = $_SESSION["loggedIn"];
    $userName = $_SESSION["userName"];
    $userId = $_SESSION["userId"];
    echo "";
?>
```

what I'm wondering is, my users log in through a jQuery.ajax() call, where I call a PHP script that does a select to check if user/pass combo exists and I update the page to indicate if they logged in/ no user/pass match.

Assuming they log in, where do I change these session variables after the ajax call succeeds? is the $_SESSION variable global in that I can update the variables in the script that validates user log in?

***UPDATE***
so I'm doing the following at the top of my body element

```
<?php
        // get session variables, check if logged in
            $loggedIn = false;
            if (isset($_SESSION["loggedIn"]) && !is_null($_SESSION["loggedIn"])) {
                echo "not null or empty";
                $loggedIn = $_SESSION["loggedIn"];
            } else {
                echo "<div class='text-color-white'>NULLS</div>";
            }

            $hiddenLoggingDiv = "";
            if ($loggedIn === true) {
                $userName = $_SESSION["userName"];
                $userId = $_SESSION["userId"];
                $hiddenLoggingDiv = "<div id='logging-validation-hidden' class='display-none'>username-".$username."-userId-".$userId."</div>";
            } else {
                $hiddenLoggingDiv = "<div id='logging-validation-hidden' class='display-none'>username-null-userId-null</div>";
            }

            echo $hiddenLoggingDiv;

        ?>
```

and I'm setting the session variable values when someone logs in (otherwise they are not logged in and the default page appears), but I'm logging in, and every time I refresh the page or open a new tab I get the echo "NULLS", which means its getting the default "false" value that I set for the logged in session variable.

What's the correct way of doing this?

inside log in php script:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT dd_id FROM user_personal_info WHERE dd_username='".$username."' AND dd_password='".$password."'")) {
            $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
            if ($row_cnt > 0) {
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $userId = $row["dd_id"];
                $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = true;
                $_SESSION["userName"] = $userName;
                $_SESSION["userId"] = $userId;
                echo "success-".$username."-".$userId;
            } else {
                echo "Invalid username or password";
                //invalid user/pass
            }
            /* close result set */
            $result->close();
        }
```

Comment: Yes, `$_SESSION` variables are globals. `This is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable. This simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script. There is no need to do global $variable; to access it within functions or methods.` http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: I'm having some trouble, please see my update to the question

Comment: You've written `// Set session variables`, yet you are actually setting other variables **with** `$_SESSION` variable. You got it backwards. You should write `$_SESSION["loggedIn"] = $loggedIn;` to actually **write** into the `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: @D4V1D I know, sorry, ignore the comment, I'm actually setting the variables in the log in script (which is another one), here I just get them to see if someone is logged in

Comment: Still, I cannot see in your code **where** you initialize `$_SESSION["loggedIn"];`.

Comment: Are you sure `"success-".$username."-".$userId;` is printed out?

Comment: yea, I've tested that repeatedly, everything from that echo, to the corresponding ajax.success function works

Comment: @D4V1D do I have to add `session_start();` to my external php files too? yea I just tested and it worked, thanks for all the help!